# FireBase-Ads jar with play-services-analytics jar

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

i am working with Google-Analytics for some while and everything works fine.

in the app gradle file it looks like this:

> compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0')

recently i added firebase-Ads to my app

in the app gradle file it looks like this:

> compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0')

it all compiles

but when i excecute the following command:

> GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mCtx);

i get NoSuchMethodException

what can it be?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You should pass play-services-analytics to 9.4.0.
Try this
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0')